# If I KILL(SPID), what happen the running transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a procedure, currently running at one SPID. Now, I found the query running too slow. In this Proc update/insert going on. If I kill the session, will what happen?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will stop executing the query and rollback any open transactions.  That rollback will undo any changes that haven't been fully committed.  Since SQL Server adheres to the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principle, you shouldn't be able to leave your database in a bad state, even by killing SPIDs.  That isn't to say you couldn't leave your data in a bad state, i.e. not wrapping multiple operations in a transaction to enforce consistency upon failure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx). In a nutshell which ever spid you kill will be disconnected

> KILL can be used to terminate a normal connection, which internally terminates the transactions that are associated with the specified session ID